# How a customized DB field is saved to DB with in the graph-Acumatica

Tags: database, save, acumatica

Suppose `POLine` has a `UsrCustomfield` and also have some calculation to populate the value for the `UsrCustomfield` based on other fields in the same `POLine`.

Which event handlers are used to populate and save the value to the DB? Saving has to be done from Graph itself... But from where?

Comment: Could you provide more information as to your existing implementation?

Comment: To be More Precise and ny requirement........There was a already existing field called CostToComplete in CostBudget Tab of Project Screen.  The value in the CostToComplete is 0.  The requirement is to populate this field  based on some condition and logic which could not be done by PXforumula....So from which event handler i should use to populate and save to DB with in the graph

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple ways to calculate the value of a custom field.

The first method is using a PXFormula attribute. This can work well if you have an easy query to calculate the value of the field. This would be set on the DAC extension of POLine that you declared the UsrCustomfield as an attribute. The help article has many different ways to accomplish this.

https://help-2018r1.acumatica.com/Wiki/(W(59936))/ShowWiki.aspx?pageid=1d25dc74-747c-4d44-8ad9-033e5a476b6f

Another way to accomplish this is trigger events based on the fields, or row, updating to re-calculate. For example, if you want to re-calculate every time the row is updated with ANY field, you can use the function:

```
public virtual void POLine_RowUpdated(PXCache sender, PXRowUpdatedEventArgs e, PXRowUpdated del)
{
    //first, invoke the base method. can be placed anywhere in your code.
    del?.Invoke(sender, e);

    //get the row
    POLine line = (POLine)e.Row;
    if (line == null) return; //always good to check if the object is not null
    //get the DAC extension from the object
    POLineExt lineExt = line.GetExtension<POLineExt>();
    decimal? CalculatedValue = 0;
    //do some calculation to figure out what the value should be

    //compare the new value against the existing value
    if(lineExt.UsrCustomField != CalculatedValue)
    {
        //set the new value
        sender.SetValueExt<POLineExt.usrCustomField>(line, CalculatedValue);
    }            
}
```

The issue with this is that it will call the code every time a POLine is updated. This may be too many calls. You can use functions to update each individual line using a FieldUpdated event on each field to recalculate as well. For example, you may want to check ExtCost:

```
public virtual void POLine_ExtCost_FieldUpdated(PXCache sender, PXFieldUpdatedEventArgs e, PXFieldUpdated del)
{
    //similar code as above            
}
```

This method is more code, and more complex, but may be needed if your logic cannot fit into a PXFormula attribute.

Comment: Thank you for reply KRichardson,

Comment: Thank for reply KRichardson.  
  Rowupdated event is not firing at all
  I am using this event
  protected void PMCostBudget_RowUpdated(PXCache cache, PXRowUpdatedEventArgs e)
        {
            PMCostBudget row = (PMCostBudget)e.Row;
            row.CuryCostToComplete = row.CuryActualPlusOpenCommittedAmount;// CuryCostToComplete is a existing DB field in project Screen
            cache.SetValueExt<PMCostBudget.curyCostToComplete>(row, row.CuryCostToComplete);
         }
 One more thing how this field is save to DB without the  save action is performed in the graph.

Comment: Ensure that the fields that you want to trigger any updates have the CommitChanges set to True on them.

Are you looking at saving this field to the database whether the changes made are actually saved? The data may be out of sync and may cause issues on the graph with changes being made on the back end, causing the record in cache to be stale.